# Does changing energy level of electron in an atom has time duration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

In quantum mechanics electron in an atom is described by the wave function of probability. When the electron changes level the wave function changes to another. Is the changing electron level when it emits or absorbs photons have any time duration or it happens immediately?

Comment: Is this a question for the lifetime of an electron in a certain energy level? Or is the question if the process of changing (jumping) between two Quantum mechanical states takes some time?

Comment: Have a look at this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00545.pdf.
The authors find that a short time before the jump occurs there are warning signs that can be used to predict the jump and to reverse it. This short time could be interpreted in some way as the duration of the jump

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but the photoelectric effect (where the electron is ejected from the material) takes a finite time and [this time has been measured experimentally](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0503-6#:~:text=The%20ultimate%20aim%E2%80%94to%20determine,has%20remained%20a%20major%20challenge.). I believe the same must be true for transitions within the atom, but I have no sources for that.

Comment: This question is about the process of changing the electron energy level to another in an atom. Does the jumping have some time?

Answer (score -1):

By the uncertainty relation $\Delta E*\Delta t\approx h$ there must be time otherwise $\Delta E$ would be very large.

Comment: The uncertainty on the energy of the jump is correlated in this way to the half-life of the excited state (short lived excited states have broader emission lines), not to the time it takes to do the actual jump.

Comment: But $\Delta t$ here is the lifetime of the excited state, $\Delta E$ the corresponding width of the line (natural line width). This is not what the question asked for...